# Sparql Query: Who has won most Academy Awards?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, wikidata

Which **SPAQRL** query shows me the people that won most Academy Awards (all times, all kind of occupations)?

This ist what I tried so far:

```
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?person count(?person) as ?anzahl
WHERE { ?person a dbo:Person .
        ?person dbo:award dbr:Academy_Award}
Group by ?person
Order by desc(count(?person))
```

The database only includes the people, not the number of Awards they have won, so `count(?person)` is always one. Can you help me?

Comment: HTH: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12366/16193